# Is it possible to know date and time of photos used in Street View?

Tags: google-maps, street-view

Is it possible to know date and time of photos used in Street View? If the answer is *yes* I'd like to know how.

It is interesting for a number of reason, for example to know exactly in what period of the year a place looks like it is on street view, or how old is that image.

Comment: The copyright is 2010 (as of this writing), but I know that the photo of my house (used as an example) was taken at least two years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google now allows you to view the date stamp on photos as part of it's historical image feature.

Answer (score 1):

You could, in theory, use the sun's position in the sky, and relate to its geographic orientation.

[Sun Calculator Help](http://www.arachnoid.com/lutusp/sunrise/sunhelp.html)

Comment: http://10k.aneventapart.com/Uploads/96/

Answer (score 0):

That would be helpful for many, but unfortunately Google Maps doesn't provide date and time to users .

Answer (score 0):

`imageDate` for StreetView has now been made available as part of [`google.maps.StreetViewPanoramaData`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?authuser=2#StreetViewPanoramaData).